# Rewrite npm script to be compatible with windows cmd

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'm trying to run a script from a tutorial that was written for a linux command line but I'm running into errors when converting it into something compatible with windows. This is the the line from the article:

```
"build": "cd react-spa && yarn build && cd .. && cp -R react-spa/build/ public/ && mv public/index.html public/app.html"
```

and this is what I have

```
cd client && yarn build && cd .. && xcopy client/build/ public/ /E && ren public/index.html app.html
```

This is the error message I get in the terminal

> ```
> Invalid number of parameters
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 4
> npm ERR! api@0.0.0 build: `cd client && yarn build && cd .. && xcopy client/build/ public/ /E && ren public/index.html app.html`
> npm ERR! Exit status 4
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the api@0.0.0 build script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-01T05_29_54_552Z-debug.log
> ```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure it's `/E` and not `/e` ? It would also be helpful if you can show the log from the debug log file `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-01T05_29_54_552Z-debug.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine your `build` script in *package.json* as follows:

```json
"build": "cd react-spa && yarn build && cd .. && xcopy /e/h/y/q \"react-spa/build\" \"public\\\" > nul 2>&1 && del \"public\\app.html\" > nul 2>&1 && ren \"public\\index.html\" \"app.html\""
```

<sub>**Note:** The aforementioned npm script assumes that you are running Windows and the default shell being utilized by npm scripts is `cmd.exe`.</sub>

---

#### Explanation:

The following changes were made to match the same behaviour as the original npm `build` script (i.e. the one that written using **nix* commands):

1. The following [`cp`](https://ss64.com/bash/cp.html) command:

   ```
   cp -R react-spa/build/ public/
   ```

   has been refined to utilize the [`xcopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) command as follows:

   ```
   xcopy /e/h/y/q \"react-spa/build\" \"public\\\" > nul 2>&1
   ```

   **Options:**

   - `/e` - Copy folders and subfolders, including empty folders.
   - `/h` - Copy hidden and system files and folders.
   - `/y` - Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file.
   - `/q` - Do not display file names while copying.

   **Notes:**

   - Each pathname has been encased in JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"...\"`
   - The `public\\` part has a trailing backslash (`\`), which has been JSON escaped (`\\`), to inform `xcopy` that the destination is a directory. This also ensures the `public` directory is created if it doesn't already exist.
   - The `> nul 2>&1` part suppresses the confirmation log that states how many files were copied.
2. The following [`mv`](https://ss64.com/bash/mv.html) command:

   ```
   mv public/index.html public/app.html
   ```

   has been refined to utilize both [`del`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html) and   [`ren`](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html) commands as follows:

   ```
   del \"public\\app.html\" > nul 2>&1 && ren \"public\\index.html\" \"app.html\"
   ```

   **Notes:**

   - We firstly attempt to delete the `app.html` file to ensure the subsequent `ren` command can rename the `index.html` file to `app.html` without any conflict due to a duplicate file already existing.

     We redirect using `> nul 2>&1` to ensure we prevent any log when the `app.html` file cannot be found, i.e. when it can't be found during the first run of the build script.
   - Each pathname has been encased in JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"...\"`.
   - The `public\\index.html` parts, in both `del` and `ren` commands, use a backslash separator (`\`),  which has been JSON escaped (`\\`). instead of a forward slash (`/`).

---